# Trying to serve IIS files on a Mac - IIS seems to see directory structure but not individual files

Tags: windows, iis, asp

So I've got a bit of a frankenstein setup - I am migrating a client's fairly old tech infrastructure (which is fairly extensive, it's a whole technology-based business) from Classic ASP to more modern architecture.

I am trying to replicate their current setup locally. The biggest problem is that to run Classic ASP, I need to do so on Windows - I am on an M Series (ARM-based) Mac. I've got a Windows 11 virtual machine running just fine and I've got IIS working and serving up files, however the problem is that when I try to serve files over a network drive (which is how the technology I am using represents my Mac's hard drive to Windows), I am getting:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

[image: Resource is unavailable]

Now I can see, and even access the files on the network drive with no problem otherwise. IIS theoretically seems to see them. IIS shows a directory of correct file names, but whenever I click one, I get the above 404 error. So somehow it is able to see the files as a directory tree, but not to serve them? It's unclear why.

[image: Top of directory listing]

If anyone has any idea why IIS would see the files in a directory structure, but not be able to serve any of them, please let me know. I imagine it's some sort of permissions or file routing issue. Unfortunately I'm not really an IIS guy - most of my devops/sysadmin type stuff has been on Linux boxes.

Comment: Try registering ASP.NET with IIS, as the failure mode you describe seems identical to that described in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler#install-products-and-components

Comment: > If you installed the .NET Framework 4.0 before you installed IIS, you'll need to run the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (aspnet_regiis.exe) to register the latest version of ASP.NET with IIS. If you don't do this, you'll find that IIS will serve static content (like HTML files) without any problems, but it will return HTTP Error 404.0 – Not Found when you attempt to browse to ASP.NET content.

Comment: @neuro CLASSIC ASP, nothing .NET. We're talking exclusively 1999 stuff. This site should have been updated 15 years ago.

And static content also fails with the exact same error, so it's definitely not this. If I navigate to a plain HTML file, I get the exact same error

Comment: The ONLY thing that works is directory structure. Both ASP files as well as static content like HTML files DO NOT.

Comment: If you relied on the virtual machine solution to serve your files from Mac to Windows, then IIS dislikes that (and does not support any kind of mapped drives). For IIS sites on Windows, use local drives and local folders.

Comment: Can you change the application pool user to somebody with more access? But I would strongly recommend just copying the files to the local disk. And could you show the acl on the network files?

Comment: @LexLi Is there anyway to trick IIS? I'd prefer my file management to be on my Mac so that I don't need to have my VSCode pointing in some weird directory that is different from the rest of my work. Would symlink folders work?

Comment: @user189695 I can theoretically change anything - it's all on my local machine, I'll have to look into doing that for the application pool user - I am not super adept with IIS at this point but since it's all local and I am the only person with access to this device or VM, I have no issue even giving it full admin privs theoretically if necessary

Comment: The limitation has been well known for more than two decades, and you won't be the last to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The VM layer is mounting the "network drive" through it's local pipeline, which is startet in user context. Nice for browsing files, when you ar a user, nice for browsing when you point a user context to that drive.

IIS is running in kernel mode (http.sys) and it's services are running in system context. They don't know anything about your userspace drives and never will. For security reasons, IIS will never execute any serveable content from such a local redirected drive.

Solution: Copy the files to a [IIS] local directory.

I am very sorry that there are no tricks to overcome this (from which I have ever heard).